# How to decompress a RAR file in Android application with out of memory exception?

Tags: java, android, rar

I am writing an Android application for decompressing RAR files with the help of **JunRar** library. But during decompression of some type of RAR files, out of memory exceptions occur.

Could somebody please help me to resolve this issue.

I know, there is a problem with **JunRar** library, but if anyone found solution, please let me know.

My analysis:

If a RAR file is compressed with a PPM algorithm, this out of memory exception occurs because an attempt is made to allocate more memory than Android device VM has.

`startSubAllocator` is allocating more memory than Android VM has by `new byte [100] MB` bytes. That exceeds available RAM of 96 MB of Android VM.

Logs attached

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

com.github.junrar.unpack.ppm.SubAllocator.startSubAllocator(SubAllocator.java:146)
com.github.junrar.unpack.ppm.ModelPPM.decodeInit(ModelPPM.java:216)
com.github.junrar.unpack.Unpack.readTables(Unpack.java:656)
com.github.junrar.unpack.Unpack.unpack29(Unpack.java:165)
com.github.junrar.unpack.Unpack.doUnpack(Unpack.java:120)
com.github.junrar.Archive.doExtractFile(Archive.java:500)
com.github.junrar.Archive.extractFile(Archive.java:442)
com.github.junrar.testutil.ExtractArchive.extractArchive(ExtractArchive.java:73)
com.github.junrar.testutil.ExtractArchive.extractArchive(ExtractArchive.java:29)
com.letusread.util.DeCompressUtil.deCompress(DeCompressUtil.java:140)
com.letusread.activity.FileListActivity$7.run(FileListActivity.java:338)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: check your internal memory of phone.

Comment: Use zip4j, worked really well for my project.

Comment: @Khawar is Zip4J supports Rar decompression?

Comment: Sorry I used it for zip files, not sure if it works for rar too.

Answer (score 1):

Help of WinRAR contains on page with title **Advanced compression parameters** the explanation:

> **Text compression/Memory to use, MB**
> Memory in megabytes allocated for PPM (can be 1-128). Higher values may increase the compression ratio, but note that PPM uses an equal memory size both to compress and decompress, so if you allocate too much memory when creating an archive, other people may have problems when unpacking it on a computer with less memory installed. If this field is set to 0, WinRAR will choose the memory size automatically.

The help page with title **Switch -MC - set advanced compression parameters** and text file **Rar.txt** (manual for console version) contain a similar statement on memory requirements for advanced text compression.

128 MB of free (perhaps even continuous) memory is needed for unpacking a RAR archive which was created using advanced text compression with 128 MB memory usage. Nothing can be done to extract files from such a RAR archive if there is not enough free memory.

---

Text file **Rar.txt** contains also information about memory requirements for solid archives on compression and decompression (switch `-md`):

> For RAR 4.x archive format the dictionary size can be:
> 64 KB, 128 KB, 256 KB, 512 KB, 1 MB, 2 MB, 4 MB.
>
> For RAR 5.0 archive format the dictionary size can be:
> 128 KB, 256 KB, 512 KB, 1 MB, 2 MB, 4 MB, 8 MB, 16 MB, 32 MB, 64 MB, 128 MB, 256 MB, 512 MB, 1 GB.
>
> When archiving, RAR needs about 6x memory of specified dictionary size, so 512 MB and 1 GB sizes are available in 64 bit RAR version only. When extracting, slightly more than a single dictionary size is allocated, so both 32 and 64 bit versions can unpack archives with all dictionaries up to and including 1 GB.

---

To answer your question: You cannot do anything in your application if a RAR archive was created on a Windows PC using excessive memory and there is not enough free memory for decompression. Alternate decompression algorithms with less memory usage for those RAR archives do not exist.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, it seems to be a bug of the implementation. This is the workaround I have used in order to avoid the problem:

In com.github.junrar.unpack.ppm.ModelPPM.java , line 196: MaxMB = unpackRead.getChar();

the method getChar, in some weird situations, return a very big number. It should be due to a broken header or a header option not supported by junrar.

My workaround was to check if MaxMB was greater than 1 and set to 1. I've been using this fix for a long time without problems.

```
int MaxMB = 0; if (reset) {
    MaxMB = unpackRead.getChar();
    if (MaxMB > 1) { //Workaround
        MaxMB = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @yopablo, I've just tried your workaround and looks like it works. But I faced one strange problem, when I take junrar sources from github extracting files is running extremely slow, Maven version works just fine. I know this answer is quite old but maybe you still remember which version of the sources you used?

Comment: If somebody run into the same problem: Maven and Jar versions of this library decompress file just fine, but adding sources directly into the projects dramatically slows decompression, I think there is some reasonable explanation but for me, it looks like mistyc. So I applied @yapablo's fix and built my own Jar, and it works just fine.